# JRE source files in Eclipse

Tags: glassfish, java

I am not able to look at JDK classes, i installed glassfish wich comes with the JDK and JRE and i have tried everything to add the sources to eclipse but no luck, the src.zip does not exist on the glassfish installer.

the src.zip does not exist on JRE6 so how the h can i add the sources to Eclipse?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to re-download the JDK , installed it then grabbed the src.zip and place it manually in my c:\glassfish3   installation, now it's fine.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must use the JDK not JRE in Eclipse if you want to gain access to the Java source automatically.

Go to preferences-> Installed JREs and add a JDK path to Eclipse. The use that one in you project class path.

Answer (score 0):

**src.zip** is generally in the root directory of a JDK (but not in a JRE). You can download a Sun / Oracle JDK from the main Oracle site at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html